# QWebEngine download restart after a reboot

Tags: qt, c++11, qwebengineview

I did an application to download softwares. It's works well with QWebengine.

For the second version, I need to implement the **restart of the download after the application is turned off**.

My goal is to get possible to restart the same download at the same status after a reboot.

Is it possible?

How to save the status of the current download in a file  with WebEngineDownloadItem ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did :

DownloaderWidget.hpp

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADERWIDGET_HPP
#define DOWNLOADERWIDGET_HPP

# include <QUrl>
# include <QApplication>
# include <QPushButton>
# include <QString>
# include <QWidget>
# include <QLabel>
# include <QVBoxLayout>
# include <QProgressBar>
# include "downloadermanager.hpp"


class DownloaderWidget : public QWidget
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit DownloaderWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    signals:

    public slots:
        void                download(void);
        void                pause(void);
        void                resume(void);
    private slots:
        void                progress(int percent);
    private:
        static QString const
                            URL;
        QLabel              *m_url;
        QPushButton         *m_start;
        QPushButton         *m_resume;
        QPushButton         *m_pause;
        QProgressBar        *m_status;
        DownloaderManager   *m_download_manager;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADERWIDGET_HPP
```

DownloaderManager.hpp

```
    #ifndef DOWNLOADERMANAGER_HPP
#define DOWNLOADERMANAGER_HPP

# include <QUrl>
# include <QObject>
# include <QDebug>
# include <QNetworkAccessManager>
# include <QNetworkRequest>
# include <QNetworkReply>
# include <QFile>
# include <QByteArray>
# include <QStandardPaths>

class DownloaderManager : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit            DownloaderManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    signals:
        void                downloadComplete(void);
        void                progress(int const percentage);
    public slots:
        void                download(QUrl const &url);
        void                pause();
        void                resume();
    private slots:
        void                download(QNetworkRequest &request);
        void                finished();
        void                downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal);
        void                error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code);
    private:
        QNetworkAccessManager
                            *m_manager;
        QNetworkRequest     m_request;
        QNetworkReply       *m_reply;
        QFile               *m_file;
        qint64              m_downloadSizeAtPause;
        QString             m_name;
        QString             get_file_name(QUrl const &url);
};

#endif // DOWNLOADERMANAGER_HPP
```

DownloaderWidget.cpp

```
    #include "downloaderwidget.hpp"

QString const               DownloaderWidget::URL = "My great URL";

                            DownloaderWidget::DownloaderWidget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent),
        m_url(new QLabel(URL, this)),
        m_start(new QPushButton("Start", this)),
        m_resume(new QPushButton("Resume", this)),
        m_pause(new QPushButton("Pause", this)),
        m_status(new QProgressBar(this)),
        m_download_manager(new DownloaderManager(this))
{
    QVBoxLayout             *main_layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    m_status->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    main_layout->addWidget(m_url);
    main_layout->addWidget(m_status);
    main_layout->addWidget(m_start);
    main_layout->addWidget(m_pause);
    main_layout->addWidget(m_resume);
    QObject::connect(m_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(download()));
    QObject::connect(m_pause, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(pause()));
    QObject::connect(m_resume, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(resume()));
    QObject::connect(m_download_manager, SIGNAL(downloadComplete()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(m_download_manager, SIGNAL(progress(int)), this, SLOT(progress(int)));
    this->m_pause->setEnabled(false);
    this->m_resume->setEnabled(false);
}

void                        DownloaderWidget::download(void)
{
    this->m_download_manager->download(QUrl(URL));
    this->m_start->setEnabled(false);
    this->m_pause->setEnabled(true);
}

void                        DownloaderWidget::pause()
{
    this->m_download_manager->pause();
    this->m_pause->setEnabled(false);
    this->m_resume->setEnabled(true);
}

void                        DownloaderWidget::resume(void)
{
    this->m_download_manager->resume();
    this->m_pause->setEnabled(true);
    this->m_resume->setEnabled(false);
}

void                        DownloaderWidget::progress(int percent)
{
    this->m_status->setValue(percent);
}
```

DownloaderManager.cpp

```
    #include "downloadermanager.hpp"

                            DownloaderManager::DownloaderManager(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_manager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this)),
        m_request(),
        m_reply(nullptr),
        m_file(nullptr),
        m_downloadSizeAtPause(0),
        m_name("")
{

}

QString                     DownloaderManager::get_file_name(QUrl const &url)
{
    QStringList             list = url.toString().split("/");
    this->m_name = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation) + "/" + list[list.length() - 1];

    return (this->m_name + ".download");
}

void                        DownloaderManager::download(QUrl const &url)
{
    this->m_name = this->get_file_name(url);
    qDebug() << "Download : file = " << this->m_name;
    this->m_downloadSizeAtPause = 0;
    this->m_request = QNetworkRequest(url);
    this->m_file = new QFile(this->m_name);
    this->m_file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append);
    if (this->m_file->size() != 0)
        this->resume();
    else
        this->download(this->m_request);
}

void                        DownloaderManager::pause(void)
{
    qDebug() << "pause()";
    if(this->m_reply == nullptr)
        return;
    QObject::disconnect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finished()));
    QObject::disconnect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
            this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
    QObject::disconnect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

    this->m_reply->abort();
    this->m_file->write(this->m_reply->readAll());
    this->m_reply = nullptr;
}

void                        DownloaderManager::resume(void)
{
    qDebug() << "resume()";

    this->m_file->flush();
    this->m_downloadSizeAtPause = this->m_file->size();
    QByteArray rangeHeaderValue = "bytes=" + QByteArray::number(this->m_downloadSizeAtPause) + "-";
    this->m_request.setRawHeader("Range",rangeHeaderValue);

    this->download(this->m_request);
}

void                        DownloaderManager::download(QNetworkRequest &request)
{
    qDebug() << "download( QNetworkRequest& request )";

    this->m_reply = this->m_manager->get(request);
    QObject::connect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finished()));
    QObject::connect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
            this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
    QObject::connect(this->m_reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
}

void                        DownloaderManager::finished(void)
{
    qDebug() << "finihsed";

    this->m_file->rename(this->m_name + ".download", this->m_name);
    this->m_file->close();
    this->m_file = nullptr;
    this->m_reply = nullptr;
    emit downloadComplete();
}

void                        DownloaderManager::downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug() << "Download Progress: Received=" << this->m_downloadSizeAtPause + bytesReceived <<": Total=" << this->m_downloadSizeAtPause + bytesTotal;

    this->m_file->write(this->m_reply->readAll());
    int                     percentage =
            static_cast<int>((this->m_downloadSizeAtPause + bytesReceived) * 100 ) / (this->m_downloadSizeAtPause + bytesTotal);
    qDebug() << percentage;
    emit progress(percentage);
}

void                        DownloaderManager::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)
{
    qDebug() << "Error:" <<code;
}
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <QApplication>
#include "downloaderwidget.hpp"

int                         main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication            app(argc, argv);
    DownloaderWidget        downloader;

    downloader.show();
    return (app.exec());
}
```

I hope this piece of code will help some one in the same case than me Thank you